# How enforce group limit access in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Let's assume I have 1 `userPool` and 2 groups: `group_a` and `group_b`.
A user can be in `group_a` or in `group_b` or without a group.

Using cognito [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoncognitouserpools.html) how can I implement access control following the following rule:
`group_a` users can `ListUsers` of every user in the pool.
`group_b` users can `ListUsers` of users from `group_b` and without a group.
Users without a group can't `ListUsers`.

Reading through AWS docs, I couldn't find a way to do without managing 2 `userPool`s and cross the identity pools and roles.
Is it possible to do it in a single UserPool?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is supported out of the box. IAM policies don't have any request conditions that check for group that a user belongs to. Also, list user returns all users and if you need any filtering you need to do it after fetching all users.
I would suggest you build APIs to handle this which check for group in the token and then return users that the group has permission to view.